# 10,000 Steps a day rule, what science is it based on?

Tags: exercise, health

I hear from many sources that 10,000 steps a day is the golden number for keeping you healthy. is there a scientific base for this. why not 15,000 or 8000.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is nothing scientific why one would walk 10.000 steps over let's say, 8.000 steps or 12.000 steps. It dates back to somewhere in the 1960s, by a company in Japan. They created a product which name would be "10.000 steps meter".

Studies later confirmed that people who walk 10.000 steps a day have lower blood pressure, more stable glucose levels and better moods. Recently studies have shown that 15.000 steps would be even better, lowering cholesterol levels and thus lowering heart disease risks.

**TLDR: 10.000 steps became popular in the 1960s thanks to a Japanese product and the number is still used often because of this.**

Comment: Nice answer. Do you know the name of the product/campaign?

Comment: @Pablo The product was called "Manpo-Kei", which literally translates to 10.000 steps meter. "Man" means 10.000, "po" means step or steps, and "Kei" means meter or system, according to some articles I found online.