# Using Google Fit - If I get my heart points (from cycling), should I care about getting my steps in?

Tags: bicycling, walking, heart

Just started using Google Fit. I cycle fairly regularly, and quickly hit my target heart points per week - but I'm rarely hitting my steps goals per day. Does this matter? If I'm getting my exercise from cycling, can I just ignore the steps goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For health benefits, you can ignore the step count.

The [CDC](https://www.cdc.gov/physicalactivity/basics/adults/index.htm), [American Heart Association](https://www.heart.org/en/healthy-living/fitness/fitness-basics/aha-recs-for-physical-activity-in-adults#:%7E:text=Recommendations%20for%20Adults,preferably%20spread%20throughout%20the%20week.), and [Mayo Clinic](https://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/fitness/expert-answers/exercise/faq-20057916) simply recommend adults get a minimum of 150 minutes of moderate-intensity cardio per week (or 75 minutes of very vigorous cardio). The CDC itself shows one example of what is considered "moderate-intensity" as "brisk walking".

[image: Diagram shown on the CDC showing examples of healthy amounts of exercise]

This is just an example though. There isn't a specification of what kind of cardio is necessary. The only important thing is to elevate your heart rate while exercising (as opposed to ingesting a bunch of caffeine pills or something).

Answer (score 1):

[10,000 steps is am artificial goal invented as a pun in Japanese](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/38381/8039). Getting the actual exercise is the important part, with the caveat, of course, that minutes of higher heart rate is also a slightly artificial goal in that increased heart rate doesn't always correlate with increased exercise. That said, it's probably a closer metric.